# Pass 2 variables to Paypal

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, paypal, contact-form-7

I'm trying to pass 2 variables within a contact form to Paypal. I've got one of them working but not both. I can see in the console that the 2 variables are being collected but there's something going wrong. I'm using contact form 7 plugin and putting my javascript in there. Hence the `on_sent_ok`

```
on_sent_ok: " my_name = jQuery('#fullname').val();"
on_sent_ok: " my_price = jQuery('#price').val();"
on_sent_ok: " console.log(my_name);"
on_sent_ok: " console.log(my_price);"
on_sent_ok: "location = 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=patrick%40thefitnessacademy%2eie&lc=IE&amount='+my_price%2e00&currency_code=EUR&button_subtype=services&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHosted&item_name=Personal Training Course for ' +my_name;"
```

Comment: whats the error mesage you geting ??

Comment: sorry, of course. The error is 'Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are missing closing single quote (`'`) and concatenation operator (`+`) after `...%2eie&lc=IE&amount='+my_price`, try:

> location =
>   'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=patrick%40thefitnessacademy%2eie&lc=IE&amount='+my_price+'%2e00&currency_code=EUR&button_subtype=services&bn=PP%2dBuyNowBF%3abtn_buynowCC_LG%2egif%3aNonHosted&item_name=Personal
>   Training Course for ' +my_name;